# Bootstrap DataTable exclude certain visible columns from export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I can export dynamically selected visible columns to pdf with the following. However I want to be able to also exclude certain visible columns (button columns) too. How do I do this?

```
buttons: [{
  extend: 'csv',
  orientation: 'landscape',
  pageSize: 'LEGAL',
  text: 'Export as CSV',
  exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible'
  }
}, {
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  orientation: 'landscape',
  pageSize: 'LEGAL',
  text: 'Export as PDF',
  exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible'
}, {
  extend: 'colvis',
  text: 'Show/Hide Columns'
}]
```

Comment: Are you able to provide more information or a working example?

Comment: This buttons{...} section is all that is required to explain the issue. The is a DataTables version 1.10 question. The configuration in question is this one { extend: 'pdfHtml5', orientation: 'landscape', pageSize: 'LEGAL', text: 'Export as PDF',
exportOptions:{columns:':visible'}
}, I assume there has to be a way to denote print all visible columns except these columns [0,1] for instance. There is an option to allow printing of all visible columns and targeted columns columns: [ 0, ':visible' ] but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to add a method to the columns property in the export options that filters if the column is visible and if the column is not part of the columns you do not want to export. The idx variable is the column index.

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/L06yu0vz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Do not export these columns
  var hideFromExport = [0,1,2];

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'copyHtml5',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: function ( idx, data, node ) {
          var isVisible = table.column( idx ).visible();
          var isNotForExport = $.inArray( idx, hideFromExport ) !== -1;
          return isVisible && !isNotForExport ? true : false; 
        }
      }
    }, 'colvis']
  });
});
```

Comment: My requirement is not to export hard coded columns like 0,1 etc but to export all visible columns and I have been successful in doing that using {columns:':visible'} but I need to go a step further and export all visible columns BUT not visible column 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you try exportOptions:{columns:':visible:not:(nth-child(4))'} ?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :visible:not:(nth-child(4)) I tried to simplify your expression and remove :visible in order to locate the issue but also got unrecognized expression for {columns:'not:(:nth-child(4))'}. This syntax is good {columns:':nth-child(4)'} so the not syntax is not correct.

Comment: If that jQuery css selector does not work, I would go with the first option and build an array by iterating over all your columns and checking if they are visible, excluding the columns you do not want exported.

Comment: tried this approach, exportOptions:{columns:"#placePendingShareTabTable td:nth-child(2)').nextUntil(':nth-child(4):visible"}. while it selects correctly in browser js wndow, I get an error when clicking on the button in the application.

Comment: @jimmy I was able to figure it out. I updated my answer above. It took me a lot of work to solve this. As I'm sure you know, the documentation has nothing about excluding data.

Comment: How do I mark a question as solved? I don't see any obvious option.

Comment: @jimmy click the green check image

Comment: @jimmy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see a green image. It shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @jimmy Are you using the mobile app, or a desktop web browser? Did you look at the link 2 comments up?

Comment: @jimmy The exact instructions from the stack overflow help are "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."